# Onebox should not require the title slug in URL to be at least 10 characters

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, title, onebox

I was trying to onebox [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548762/void-f) in chat, so typed the direct URL, expecting it to onebox:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548762/void-f
```

It [didn't](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4399903#4399903).

Messing around in the [chat sandbox](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/651/sandbox), I figured the URL title slug (the part after question ID) must be 10 characters or more in order for the question to be oneboxed, or be omitted. (e.g. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548762` will be [oneboxed](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4399899#4399899) as well.)

Since "void-f" is only 6 characters, it wasn't oneboxed.

Can this check please be removed? Can't see any real benefit from this, and  it's just making it harder to onebox valid questions.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is a bug or a feature of oneboxing?

Comment: @quartata my best guess is that in the past, they did not omit non-English characters from the title, so the title stub was always long enough, and they started to omit characters, they forgot about this restriction. So, bug by design?